# DirectX AudioVideoPlayback and selecting a device and/or panning

Tags: vb.net, directx, directx-9

Currently using VS2010, DirectX 9, Winforms, .Net 3.5, VB.

I'm creating an application that will play MP3 files through the left and right channels of a sound card. It will also need to play another MP3 file through the centre/rear channel when triggered.
I'm currently using DirectX Audio class to play the MP3 files which works fine, but I can't see a way of selecting the device or channel that each sound stream is sent to.

I've looked at a few libs such as OpenTK and BASS.Net. BASS.Net seems promising, but I need to try to avoid the license fee if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/). I've never used it for audio, but it's better than some of the libraries you mention.

Comment: I'm currently looking at SlimDX and trying to use XAudio2. The issue is that I'm getting an access violation exception and I'm unable to select which device I want to use.

Comment: `Dim Device As XAudio2 = New XAudio2
        Dim l_File As FileStream = File.OpenRead(s_ContentLocation & "Waves\" & filename)
        Dim l_WaveStream As WaveStream = New WaveStream(l_File)
        Dim l_Buffer As New AudioBuffer
        l_Buffer.AudioData = l_WaveStream
        l_Buffer.AudioBytes = CInt(l_WaveStream.Length)
        l_Buffer.Flags = BufferFlags.EndOfStream
        Dim l_Source As SourceVoice = New SourceVoice(Device, l_WaveStream.Format)
        l_Source.SubmitSourceBuffer(l_Buffer)
        l_Source.Start()`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you there, I've never used the XAudio2 API... you may try asking for help in the SlimDX group here http://groups.google.com/group/slimdx-devel, or googling for some samples.

Comment: I've spent half a day looking for examples xD
Thanks for the link though, that's something I hadn't come across yet. All other links pointed to Gamedev.net and since it's not a game I'm creating, I didn't feel right posting there.
Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't need anything fancy, you can make 3D sound (and therefore implement what you want) by using DirectSound, you can find more samples and help for it. Also, if you can live without the centre/rear channel support, NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com) is really easy to use.